# When I try to detach() is returning the error: local.ERROR: Call to a member function programs() on integer

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this Many to Many relationship between Courses and Programs. I can insert new courses and add as many programs as I want and it's returning correctly. The problem is on Update. I can fecth all data in my Course update form and all Programs that was selected through checkboxes checked or unchecked.

My idea is when I update the Course, I want to delete all Programs related (detach()) and attach again according to Programs checked in the update form.

The problem happens when I call the update method and it calls the detach().

My models are:

Course (model):

```
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'title', 'description', 'is_active'
    ];

    public function programs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Program::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Program (model):

```
class Program extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'is_active'
    ];

    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

My update on CoursesController:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required'
    ]);

    // $course = Course::whereId($id)->update($request->all());
    $course = Course::whereId($id)->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'is_active' => $request->is_active
    ]);

    $course->programs()->detach();
    $program = Program::find($request->programs);
    $course->programs()->attach($program);

    return response()->json([
        'course' => $course,
        'message' => 'Course has been Updated!'
    ]);
}
```

my Course Vuejs component:

```
<template>
...
</template>
<script>
export default {

    data(){
        return {
            course:{
                name: '',
                title: '',
                description: '',
                is_active: true,
                programs: []
            },
            courses: [],
            uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/',
            errors: [],
            new_update_course: [],
            toastr: toastr.options = {"positionClass": "toast-top-full-width"},

            programs: [],
            uriPrograms: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/activePrograms/',
        }
    },

    methods: {

        ...

        loadUpdateCourseModal(index){
            this.errors = [];
            $("#update-course-modal").modal("show");
            this.new_update_course = this.courses[index];

            this.new_update_course.programs.forEach(program => {
                this.new_update_course.programs.push(program.id)
            });
        },

        ...

        updateCourse(){
            axios.patch(this.uri + this.new_update_course.id, {
                name: this.new_update_course.name,
                title: this.new_update_course.title,
                description: this.new_update_course.description,
                is_active: this.new_update_course.is_active,
                programs: this.new_update_course.programs
            }).then(response =>{
                $("#update-course-modal").modal("hide");
                toastr.success(response.data.message);
            }).catch(error=>{ 
                if(error.response.data.errors.name){
                    this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.name[0]);
                }
                if(error.response.data.errors.title){
                    this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.title[0]);
                }
                if(error.response.data.errors.description){
                    this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.description[0]);
                }
            });
        },

        ...

    },

    mounted(){
        ...
    }
}
</script>
```

If I try to update the course with id = 2, for example, in my laravel log, the error is:

> local.ERROR: Call to a member function programs() on integer {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function programs() on integer at /Users/GiselleTavares/Documents/.../app/Http/Controllers/CoursesController.php:120)
>   [stacktrace]
>
> ## 0 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\CoursesController->update(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), '2')

The line for CoursesController.php:120 is:

```
$course->programs()->detach();
```

I don't understand what this error means...

> Call to a member function programs() on integer ...

If I comment these 3 lines below, I can update the course data but, of course, without changes on Programs relationship...

```
$course->programs()->detach();
$program = Program::find($request->programs);
$course->programs()->attach($program);
```

If I comment just the detach() line, the attach() line show the same error above. However, I use exactly the same (without the detach()) on my store() and it's working.

Any ideas? I tried to find solutions but nothing helped...

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson This one: Laravel Framework 5.8.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `update()` function [returns an integer](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_update) indicating whether or not the update (which is a **bulk** update, because `Course::whereId($id)` returns a collection of results, not a single one).

This should work:

```
$course = Course::findOrFail($id);

$course->update([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'title' => $request->title,
    'description' => $request->description,
    'is_active' => $request->is_active
]);
```

Comment: Thank you. This error is gone but the detach() is still not working properly. Something weird happens: If I update and check some Program for the Course, it correctly appears in the first time. If I update it again, the new changes are not applying. Let me try to figure out and understand if it comes from the same problem. No errors appear...

Comment: I just tested and the detach and attach is working properly. Your solution helped me! The other problem has nothing about it :)

Answer (score 0):

The `update()` method is going to return a `boolean` value so `$course` is not going to be the model you want to update. As for why the error is saying `integer` instead of `boolean` I'm not 100% sure.

There are a couple of solutions to get the corse:

1. Just use `find()` or `findOrFail()`

   ```
   $course = Course::findOrFail($id);
   ```
2. Use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

   ```
   public function update(Request $request, Course $course)
   ```

Going with option 1 as an example your code would look something like:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name'  => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
    ]);

    $course = Course::findOrFail($id);

    $course->update([
        'name'        => $request->name,
        'title'       => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'is_active'   => $request->is_active,
    ]);

    $course->programs()->sync($request->input('programs', []));

    return response()->json([
        'course'  => $course,
        'message' => 'Course has been Updated!',
    ]);
}
```

In the above example I have used [sync()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) instead of detaching and the attaching the new ids.

Comment: Thank you. But if I try to use sync, I get this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'description' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `course_program` (`course_id`, `created_at`, `description`, `id`, `is_active`, `name`, `pivot`, `program_id`, `updated_at`) values (2, 2019-04-25 01:58:38, asdfdsfsdfsd sdfsfsdf, 3, 1, T768, 2, 0, 2019-04-25 19:08:08)) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] ...`. My pivot table only have the ids and timestamps. How to set only what I want instead of get all data?

Comment: If I try the Route Model Biding, I have the same behavior than using `$course = Course::findOrFail($id);`. Which means: it updates the Programs associated only in the first time. I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: @GiTavares My method is essentially the same as the accepted answer so I'm not sure why you would be getting that error with `$corse->update(...)`?!? Did you copy an paste my example?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is not on the `$course = Course::findOrFail($id);` as the accepted answer, it is working and the error with detach() is gone. The problem is with the `$course->programs()->sync($request->input('programs', []));`. It's trying to send data to the columns on my pivot table that doesn't exist. In this case, I keep using detach() and attach() successfully. To be clear: My $request has data to my Course table and the pivot table as well. Using the sync() as you said, will try to send all this $request data to my pivot table, wrongly.

Comment: @GiTavares Ah fair enough, I'd assumed that `$request->programs` was just an array of `id`'s, I'm guessing now that it's not. Which is why I'd used `sync()` because it should end up doing the same job as `detach()` and `attach()`. Either way, I'm glad you managed to fix your problem.